# JavaScript unicode aware string slice

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode, ascii

I am trying to slice the string containing Unicode characters. but it returns a replacement character. here is my sample code.

```
let str = ' ';
str = str.slice(0, -1); 
console.log(str);
```

which gives me below result

> " �"

how can I get rid of the replacement character?

Comment: What output do you want? an Error? ` ` or ` `?

Comment: @Kaiido output should be   without .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, it won't break a 4 byte character into 2:

```js
let str = ' ';
str = [...str].slice(0, -1).join(''); 
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because your  is a [*surrogate pair*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+0000_to_U+D7FF_and_U+E000_to_U+FFFF), which means that it is represented as four bytes (two code units á 2 bytes, UTF-16). As `.slice` works on code units (as all other string methods), you need to slice away the *pair*:

```js
let str = ' ';
str = str.slice(0, -2); 
console.log(str);
```

To work with *code points*  instead of *code units* you can use the *iterator* of strings, which will iterate over the *code points* (that is one character of the string might be a string with two chars):

```js
let str = ' ';
for(const char of str)
  console.log(char, char.length);
```

You can use the iterator to build up an array, work on that, and turn the array back into a string as the other answer shows.

Comment: Arguably, the question asks for a "JavaScript unicode aware string slice", you are telling OP that "they" need to be aware of it.

Comment: Sure, but that was already covered by the other answer. Tried to elaborate a bit on the *why*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it will not work In case the string contains normal and Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

the other solution doesn't take combining marks into account. for example:

```js
foo = 'abc'
[...foo].slice(0, -1).join('')
// 'abc'
```

to account for that we need to combine those into single elements in the array:

```js
[...foo].reduce((p, c) => c.match(/\p{Emoji_Modifier}/u) ? [...p.slice(0, -1), p[p.length - 1] + c] : [...p, c], [])
// ['a', 'b', 'c', '']
```

with that the full solution is:

```js
[...foo].reduce((p, c) => c.match(/\p{Emoji_Modifier}/u) ? [...p.slice(0, -1), p[p.length - 1] + c] : [...p, c], []).slice(0, -1).join('')
// 'abc'
```